# Call function more times with other args

Tags: ghidra, x64dbg, patch-reversing

I want to call the same function more times but with other args, I can't add new instructions, so how can I call it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to use code cave:

- Find some locations with no (or useless) instructions.
- Put in there your function calls and args.
- At the end of your calls, place a jump to the instruction executing next after the original call, according to your screenshot, that would be the address 0x41B417.
- Overwrite the address of the original call (0x41B412) with a jump to your code cave (you've got 5 bytes, plenty of space for a good long jump).

Another approach would be to write a DLL, define the function's prototype, load it and call the function as many times and with any arguments as you want.